# Modifying WooCommerce product query to filter attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We are trying to create a from-to filter.
The user fills in value X in the From and/or value Y in the To.

Based on these inputs we want to add a greater or less condition to the woocommerce product query.

The following code example is one of the many examples we tried it with:

```
function alter_wc_product_loop_query($query)
{
    if ((is_product_category() || is_shop()) && $query->is_main_query()) {
         $taxes[] = [
             'taxonomy' => 'pa_horsepower-hp',
             'field'    => 'name',
             'terms'    => 100,
             'operator' => '>='
         ];

        $query->set('tax_query', $taxes);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'alter_wc_product_loop_query');
```

We also tried the action add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'alter_wc_product_loop_query');.

We also tried a meta_query:

```
$attribute_name = 'vermogen-pk'; // Replace with the attribute name
        $comparison_operator = '>'; // Replace with the desired comparison operator, e.g., >, <, >=, <=
        $comparison_value = 100; // Replace with the desired numeric value

        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => 'attribute_' . $attribute_name,
            'value'   => $comparison_value,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => $comparison_operator,
        );

        $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
```

In none of the cases it worked. It either shows all products or no products at all.

How do we filter the products with a greater or less then condition?

We tried tax_queries and meta_queries.
In both cases the filtering doesnt work.

We debugged the queries and either the query wasn't even added or the query was added and the result was no result

Comment: The `tax_query` parameter does not support mathematical operators, so that certainly won't work. Your `meta_query` logic looks okay, though I wonder if `numeric` needs to be uppercase (to match documentation). Will you please edit your question to include the SQL query that you get from your `meta_query` adjustments?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Caleb. We solved the issue in a different was, as we found it that the tax_query is not capable of delivering this solution.